# Specific categories in ZF1

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

I have this model:

```
class Application_Model_Categories extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'categories';
    protected $_referenceMap = array(
            'Stores' => array (
            'columns' => 'store_id',
            'refTableClass' => 'Application_Model_Races',
            'refColumns' => 'id')
        );
 }
```

Then in my controller:

```
$race = new Application_Model_Races();
$find = $this->race->find(1);
$current = $find->current();
$categories = $current->findDependentRowset('Application_Model_Categories');
```

this is returning all the categories. i need to apply a filter to return only the categories with parentId = 0

I´m new to ZF1 so if you also see that im getting the data incorrectly in the controller please let me know. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

```
$race = new Application_Model_Races();
$find = $this->race->find(1);
$current = $find->current();
$select = $race->getAdapter()->select()->where('parentId = 0');
$categories = $current->findDependentRowset(
    'Application_Model_Categories', 
    null, 
    $select
);
```

By providing a `Zend_Db_Select` object as third argument to `findDependentRowset` table row method call, you can add as much conditions as you want (even adding limit, setting order, ...).

**Edit**

Well, you should create a custom Row Class, name it `Application_Model_Race` for example, or `Application_Model_RaceRow`.

```
class Application_Model_RaceRow extends Zens_Db_Table_Row_Abstract
{

    public function getParentCategories()
    {
        $select = $this->getTable()->select()->where('parentId = 0');
        return $this->findDependentRowset(
            'Application_Model_Categories', 
            null, 
            $select
        );
    }

}
```

Add a `_rowClass` to your `Application_Model_Races` class.

```
class Application_Model_Races extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_rowClass = 'Application_Model_RaceRow';

    /** Your old code **/

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried that but i´m getting: Catchable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract::findDependentRowset() must be an instance of Zend_Db_Table_Select, instance of Zend_Db_Select given

Comment: @handsome Remove the `->getAdapter()`, it should appear like `$race->select()` ...

Comment: Thank you! that works. is there any other way to do this? i mean.. get the categories with parent_id = 0 directly from the model insteado of having that logic in the controller? thanks again!

Comment: also echo $race->select()->where('parent_id = 0'); outputs SELECT `races`.* FROM `races` WHERE (parent_id = 0) which makes no sense.

Comment: @handsome I updated the answer. Regarding the `SELECT races.* FROM races WHERE (parent_id = 0)`, don't carry about that. Zend will set the accurate `Table` to select from for you.